# Private or public key? Github

Tags: git, github, version-control

when I upload something to my GitHub account, it appears that my username (the one I setup on git) committed the changes, but it doesn't show the picture of my actual GitHub account, so I'm guessing that it takes it as someone else? I'm using a public key, so does that mean that I have to use my private key to show that the actual owner of the repo committed the changes? Also when I try to use my email on the git profile it says that I can't push because it would reveal the address, I had to disable that, so if I use a private key would it let me push if the option to

> Block command line pushes that expose my email

is enabled?

I'm confused in this topic to be honest, also I'm currently working on something and I have pushed a couple of lines and it still doesn't show that I've contributed to my repo, is that due to the public key?

Thanks for the helps :)

Comment: Please run `git config --list`. Is your `user.name` and `user.email` same as that of your github account?

Comment: Thanks for answering, the email was not the same, because I was trying to not expose my email, not I switched it back and it shows that I contributed on my GitHub and also shows the image. So what is the private key used for? And how can I hide my email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Github actually check the committer’s email with github account which bind with the same email address.

Assume the email address you bind with your github account is `myaccount@outlook.com` (you can also double check the email address in [Emails Tab](https://github.com/settings/emails)).

While if you committed changes with a different email address (as the email showed by `git config -l` user.email option), github will detect the committer is not the github account owner since the email addresses are different.

To change the user email in `.gitconfig` file same as the email bind with your github account, you can use below command:

```
git config --global user.email myaccount@outlook.com
```

After that, when you commit and push new changes to github, it will show the github owner as the contributor for the changes.

Besides, if you want to protect your email address not to be seen by others, you can select the option **Keep my email address private** in Emails Tab.

[image]

Comment: So what if someone tries to push with my email address ?

Comment: And what’s the purpose of the private key then?

Comment: @Arturo It's not possibly to happen for below reasons: 1. not everyone knows your email address; 2. Even if someone commit changes with your email address, if you have not added the users as Collaborators for your github repo, they have no premission to push to your github repo directly.